# Sum of a strings array using C#

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, streamwriter, subtotal

I am trying to build a console application using Web Services. Its use 2 functions. The first one `GetAllProject` outputs ptojectsID and ProjectsNames.

The second function is `GetUsersList` and it outputs the list of users. Its need as a mandatory parameter the projectID which has been requested by calling the first function.

What I would like to do its to output into a CSV file the projectID, the projectName and the totals of userIDs.

When I run the console, it worked fine but in the column for the totals of userIDs I gets as an output `System.String[]`.

I don't know what I could do to instead of extracting on each line `System.String[]` the actual total of usersIDs corresponding to each projectID

I don't know how to achieve this. Here you have my code.

```
string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\test\\test.csv");

WS.Projects[] pr = db.GetAllProject();

using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(outCsvFile))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pr.Length; ++i)
    {
        string[] subecjtsIDS = new string[] {""};
        subecjtsIDS = db.GetUsersList(pr[i].ProjectID);

        file.WriteLine(pr[i].ProjectID + ',' + pr[i].ProjectTitle + ',' + subecjtsIDS);                          

    }
}
```

Comment: `subecjtsIDS.Length` if you want a count of how many items are in the array.

Comment: If you want to view user IDs as integers, why are you handling them as strings? (And what do you expect that to mean? These would be pretty odd user IDs, for it to make sense to sum them.) If you're not looking to handle them as integers, please explain what you mean by "totals".

Comment: you stated "The second function is `GetUsersList` and it outputs the list of users"... so I'm expecting a `List<string>` instance, but that doesn't appear to be the case. please clarify..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm correctly interpreting your requirements, you're not trying to *sum* the user IDs (which wouldn't make sense), you're just trying to *list* them as part of a CSV row. Assuming that's correct...

The problem is that this line

```
file.WriteLine(pr[i].ProjectID + ',' + pr[i].ProjectTitle + ',' + subecjtsIDS);
```

Is attempting to concatenate a string array onto a string. To do this, .NET will call the array's [`.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) method, and, for most reference types in the framework, this just prints the name of the type, i.e. "System.String[]".

Instead, you need to iterate the array and print its contents. The String class provides a nice way to do this: the [`Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
file.WriteLine(pr[i].ProjectID + ',' + pr[i].ProjectTitle + ',' + String.Join(",", subecjtsIDS));
```

If, however, you're trying to add the *number of subjects* associated with each project to each line, you just want the [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx) of the array:

```
file.WriteLine(pr[i].ProjectID + ',' + pr[i].ProjectTitle + ',' + subecjtsIDS.Length);
```

Comment: Probably Count, not Join... (it is major pain to deal with variable-width CSV files  ...)

Comment: You might be right! Frankly, it's difficult to tell from the question. I've edited your suggestion in.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. The app works and it output the CSV file in question. but its been exported without headers, there's a way to include headers? thanks again

Comment: @Aarancibia, CSV is a format, and it depends on the context of the application that reads it whether or not headers are neccessary.  With that said, typically it's the first line of the CSV formatted file. Typically, you would use a return carrier to denote records (i.e. `Environment.Newline`)

Comment: @Aarancibia Glad to help. Regarding the headers, please ask a separate question, so it can have its own answers. (Hint: if you aren't explicitly writing headers to the file, where would they come from?)

Comment: @DanJ I would like to have the same 3 variables that are into the  file.WriteLine but in this case be the headers (.ProjectID,.ProjectTitle and subecjtsIDS), Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(outCsvFile))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pr.Length; ++i)
    {
        string[] subecjtsIDS = new string[] {""};
        subecjtsIDS = db.GetUsersList(pr[i].ProjectID);
        foreach(var id in subecjtsIDS)
        {
            file.WriteLine(pr[i].ProjectID + ',' + pr[i].ProjectTitle + ',' + id );
        }    
    }
}
```

This will write more rows but if you use `string.Join("," subecjtsIDS)` then the number of columns increased and your data will become very complex to understand.

Answer (score -1):

You are going to need to loop through that array and create a string where the values are comma-separated (or whatever it is you want as output).  For example:

```
string outCsvFile = string.Format(@"C:\\test\\test.csv");

WS.Projects[] pr = db.GetAllProject();

using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(outCsvFile))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pr.Length; ++i)
    {
        string[] subecjtsIDS = new string[] {""};
        subecjtsIDS = db.GetUsersList(pr[i].ProjectID);

        string formattedSubecjtsIDs;
        for (int j = 0; j < subecjtsIDs.length; j++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formattedSubecjtsIDs))
                formattedSubecjtsIDs += ", ";
            formattedSubecjtsIDs += subecjtsIDs[j];
        }

        file.WriteLine(pr[i].ProjectID + ',' + pr[i].ProjectTitle + ',' + formattedSubecjtsIDS);                          

    }
}
```

Comment: This probably not what OP wants at all... downvote for very bad way to re-implement `String.Join`.

Comment: @Alexei Would be helpful if you could provide a code snippet so OP would be able to see what you're suggesting.

Comment: @JeffPrince, Alexei means you should use `String.join(arg0, arg1)`.. it's considered bad practice to perform append string assignments in a loop.. I would pass in a delegate function to aggregate the values. then there is `String.format("{0}, {1}", whole, String.join(", ", parts))`

Comment: @Brett That makes a lot of sense.  Continually append the string object in the loop could be a performance issue if there were a lot of elements in the string[] object..

Comment: @JeffPrince [Dan J answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32336945/477420) showed couple ways one can read OP's question by the time I've made my comment - so I did not expand on possible interpretations. Again - downvote strictly for recommending what consider worst practice when combining strings, not for possible misinterpretation of unclear question.